# How will be either decrease or clear gradle-heap in android studio 4.1.3

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, heap-memory

**Error Message :Gradle project sync failed**

I am using Android studio 3.4.1 which is giving a gradle heap size error. I have increased heap size in gradle.properties.The issue is resolved on temporary basis. However, it emerges after developing few apps.

So, I shall be very thankful if someone give a permanent solution of gradle heap size.

Answer (score 0):

don't mention the size of heap, it will fix the issue.
comment out this line in gradle.properties.

```
//org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536m
```

Comment: Thank you Ranjan Kumar, you shared your opinion but if i comment as you mentioned, it is not installing app on my device. In other cases, if the android studio does not accept this change. It gives this error(Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1.).  Please share another technique to resolve the issue.